# Using sed only on grep lines in file

Tags: bash, script

I have a file which contains something like this:

```
192.168.1.1 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=true
192.168.1.2 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=true
192.168.1.3 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=true
```

Im trying to find best way to grep lines in the file that contains name=muzi and then run sed to change standalone=false to all these lines EXCEPT the first instance.
so I would have

file.txt

```
192.168.1.1 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=true
192.168.1.2 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=false
192.168.1.3 user=a pass=b name=muzi standalone=false
```

I've found a way to do that with temp files, but this code is awful and I'm sure there's a simple way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes "all these lines except the first instance" means "… except the first instance of `name=muzi`", not "… except the first instance of `name=muzi standalone=true`". So the first `name=muzi` is "the first instance", regardless what `standalone` is or even if it occurs in the line at all.

The answer also assumes you want to change exact strings `standalone=true` to `standalone=false`. E.g. `standalone=auto` will not be changed.

With `sed`, possibly not the simplest solution:

```
<datafile sed '
/\bname=muzi\b/ {   # only for lines matching the pattern
  x                 # exchange hold and pattern spaces
  s/^$//            # if former hold space empty
  t lbl             # then go to lbl
  g                 # else get the former pattern space back
  s/\bstandalone=true\b/standalone=false/     # actual replacement
  h                 # copy pattern space to hold space
  :lbl              # the label
  g                 # copy hold space to pattern space
}'
```

The hold space is initially empty. Any encounter of `name=muzi` makes the hold space non-empty. Empty hold space is an indicator `name=muzi` is beeing seen for the first time.

`\b` is an anchor that matches a word boundary. I used it where I thought it was appropriate. This way, `name=muzilla`, `fullname=muzi` or `standalone=true1` do not match.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow a different tool than grep and sed, the following replaces all occurrences:

```
awk '$4=="name=muzi" { $5 = "standalone=false" }
                     { print}'
```

To avoid replacing the first *name=muzi* line, add a test.

```
awk '$4=="name=muzi" { if (do_it) $5 = "standalone=false"
                       else do_it=1 }
                     { print }'
```

`do_it` is automatically initialized to 0 when this program starts.